Does the LOLIN D32 comply with the standards of the ESP-WROOM-32 schematic checklist?
I am working on a project that involves using the LOLIN D32 development board, which features the ESP-WROOM-32 module. I need to ensure that the board adheres to the design guidelines and schematic checklist provided by Espressif for the ESP-WROOM-32 module.
I’ve reviewed the available documentation and design guidelines from Espressif, but I’m unsure if the LOLIN D32 board specifically follows all the recommended practices outlined for the ESP-WROOM-32 module.
Specifically, I’m looking to confirm:

Power Supply Design: Does the LOLIN D32 meet the recommended voltage and decoupling requirements?
Grounding: Is the grounding strategy used in the LOLIN D32 in line with Espressif’s guidelines?
Antenna Design: Does the board’s antenna placement and layout conform to the standards recommended by Espressif?
Signal Integrity and EMC: Are there any known issues or considerations related to the LOLIN D32’s compliance with the ESP-WROOM-32 checklist?

If anyone has performed a detailed comparison of the LOLIN D32 board with the ESP-WROOM-32 schematic checklist or has insights into its compliance, I would greatly appreciate your input.

do you have links for specs?
